# How to tag friend name in status message using Facebook Graph API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Asp.Net MVC. I am trying to post a message on facebook wall using Facebook Graph API. For that i am using following endpoint,

```
 POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

and sending parameters `Access_Token` and `message`. and it is working fine.

In my scenario i will send a message to my friend with his name within the text. like 
`Hello Mr.<friend name> have your dinner` and my friend name should appear as a link and it should link to his profile page. 
I have followed the following [link](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/), But it doesn't help for me.

I tried with tags parameter and it also doesn't help for me.

I tried to prepare message_tags array and send to api and it throws 400 Bad request since it is read-only property.

Please guide me the way that i can accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To tag people(friends) in your feed message, youo have to use Open Graph Concept - [Mention Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/).

There's no other way you can tag people in a post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am unable to publish action type in order to set optional properties permissions. please guide me.